# Excel VBA missing Microsoft outlook 15.0 reference and “Error in loading DLL”

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have been given an Excel work book to fix. What ever I click I get “Error in loading DLL” (e.g. I cannot access the modules). 
I can also see "MISSING: Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library" in the References section. 14.0 is available on the list but not 15.0
Anybody has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: When this happens on my work, you can't do anything... its your excel version. Someone else may be able to fix this, you can't. (At least to my knowledge)

As for the missing libraries, you uncheck the missing one and check the one you have with your version... 14, 15, 16... But it will give you an error trying to do so.

Comment: I think it's all connected (the missing Library is a dll file). I have tried earlier what you suggested but it does not work unfortunately.

Comment: You can't fix the file, someone else with a different version of office might. If the file is not too large you can try to start a fresh workbook and copy paste your sheets & modules.

Comment: try opening in safe mode and see if it will allow you to remove reference and add correct one.

Comment: Safe mode excel does not help (same errors and no access to macros).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do late binding for the Microsoft Outlook Object Library because, as is the case here, you have an earlier library than the one that the code was written with. By using late binding, Excel will look for the right library itself.

Uncheck the reference that is missing.

Replace the part of your code that has the outlook references with this (example)...

```
Dim objApp As Object
Dim objMailItem As Object
Const olMailItem As Long = 0 'Outlook Mail Item constant

Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objMailItem = objApp.CreateItem(0)
With objMailItem
    .To = strTo
    .CC = strCC
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I access the code ? I keep getting "Error loading dll" message every time I open a module

Comment: You should be able to go to the VBE by pressing ALT + F11 once the workbook is open. I thought you were already in the VBE because you have obviously seen the missing reference.

Comment: That I know already. I am trying to say that the pop up error message "Error in loading DLL" prevents me from accessing the code in the modules i.e I cannot see or modify the code, as soon as I click on the module the pop up window appears.

Comment: OK. I think I understand. So do you essentially can't open the file. THough call here... one possible way of solving it, if you can't even open in "safe mode", would be to convert the file into a .ZIP. Find the code module there and replace either the reference or all of the code (to see if it will let you open it like that).

Comment: I can open the excel file and also the VBE. But I cannot access the code owing to the error pop up window. I tried safe mode to no avail.

Comment: I tried the zipping option but I cannot see the code in the zip file/folder

Comment: @DKK get someone with a newer version of the office suite to do that. They will be able to.

Comment: New office suite is not an option :/ I just need to find a way to disable the error pop up message so I can change the code

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55796091/2127508) to a similar question help?

Comment: Yes I tried that. I still get the error message popping up, which prevents me access/modify the code.