# How can I match an element inside a range to another element in another range using a loops?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns full of tasks. One column is in sheet Daily1 and the other column is in Task List. I want my program to go to Daily1 select the first task and find it in Task List. Once it finds it in the Task list I want it to go back to Daily1 offset 7 to the right to check if there are the initials CR if so then go back to the position in Tasks List where it found the matching task from Daily 1 offset 2 to the right and fill in that cell with completed if not then fill it with incomplete. I want it to do this for each element in the Column that contains the tasks in Daily 1.

```
    Private Sub Validation()

Dim wsDaily As Worksheet
Dim wsTskL As Worksheet
Dim rngD As Range
Dim rngTL As Range



Set wsDaily = Worksheets("Daily1")
Set wsTskL = Worksheets("Task List")


Set rngD = wsDaily.Range("B7")
Set rngTL = wsTskL.Range("C2")

Do Until rngD.Value = ""
    If COUNTIF(Taks List!wsTskL,Daily!rngD.value)>0 == True Then
       If rngD.Offset(0, 7).Value = "CR" Then
            rngTL.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Completed"
            Else
            rngTL.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Incomplete"
        End If
    End If
    Set rngD = rngD.Offset(1)
Loop
End Sub
```

[Daily 1 Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ9hr.png)

[Task List Workhseet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lssAO.png)

Comment: Hi David,
can you provide the sample input and desired result also, that helps in clarifying the question.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in the response. Basically what I have is two columns in two different sheets with the same information but in a different order. I want to use the list in column A in sheet one and do the following: read the value inside the first cell of the column then go one by one in the other column comparing until you have found that first value in the second column. I want it to do this for all the values in the first column, sort of like a search function.

Comment: Do you need the column index which you found on the second sheet? There still are some blanks in your question can you provide sample data with the desired result.
or possibly create the google doc and put the URL here.

Comment: I just updated the question, hopefully, this explains better what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Hey, I have added the VBA code for what I understood you want to do. if anything else is needed provide the editable excel sheet with the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rough idea for your required formula

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A1) > 0
```

this will find A1 from sheet 1 in the A column of sheet2 if exist will set the column true else false.

> UPDATE

you are not using the formula correctly in VBA.
The below code should work for you. you might need to update the column number where you want to set the values (completed/not completed). your code does not have a workflow for what to do if not found I have just wrote not fount for that case if you don't want it just remove it.

```
Sub ExtractParts()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = Sheets("Daily1")
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = Sheets("Task List")
    Dim LastRowSrc As Long: LastRowSrc = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim LastRowDest As Long: LastRowDest = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rowRangeSrc As Range, rowRangeDest As Range
    
    Set rowRangeSrc = wsSrc.Range("B7:B" & LastRowSrc)
    Set rowRangeDest = wsDest.Range("C2:C" & LastRowDest)
    
    i = 2
    j = 7
    For Each rrow In rowRangeSrc
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rowRangeDest, rrow.Value) = 0 Then
            wsDest.Cells(i, 12).Value = "Not Found"
        Else
           If wsSrc.Cells(j, 9).Value = "CR" Then
                wsDest.Cells(i, 5).Value = "Completed"
           Else
                wsDest.Cells(i, 5).Value = "Not Completed"
           End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
    Next rrow
    
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Rohit thank you so much for the help I tried running the code and it gives me an error in loading DDL, is there a specific library I have to activate? I also was wondering if rrow is defined previously and if I just missed it.

Comment: no this code is working without any external library. no you don't have to declare rrow.

Comment: @DavidRojas what is the error you are getting

Comment: It says "Error in loading DLL", that is the error I am getting.

Comment: on which line does it redirect you to and what is the version of office

Comment: @DavidRojas reffer to this SO question 
for that error i did not faced it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398530/missing-reference-and-error-in-loading-dll

Comment: Actually I removed your code and it still gives me the same error so I don't think its coming from what you gave me.

Comment: ya this macro is working as expected i checked on sample data.

Comment: @DavidRojas was this able to sort your query.

Comment: Hi Pratap yes I was able to solve that error, the code runs but not exactly like I would like to I have pointed out the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74063802/how-to-verify-that-each-element-of-a-range-in-a-worksheet-is-also-present-in-ano?noredirect=1#comment130768650_74063802

Comment: @DavidRojas is it possible to share the worksheet, not complete but with some data for structure and debugging purposes? upload it to a dive and share its link if possible. Visually I don't see any issue in the code and why it isn't working might be some data.

Comment: Yes here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_-DhJrSD_E6WRTLUVS_mNLc_FtmMbZ_emoA1bCer-g/edit#gid=1442808649

Comment: Hi, @DavidRojas code is working totally fine. here what is happening is the placement issue of the result. the not found is not for the `Blue cheese control panel` but for the `reviewer signature` (last row of A column in Daily1)
what you can do is change the src and dest ranges.

Comment: So is the range reading from down to up and therefore I would have to change it from up to down or why is it that it is reading the reviewer signature? Also how would you suggest I change the ranges from what to what? Once again thanks so much for all the help and pateince

Comment: @DavidRojas I have answered this in another question you posted. Can you accept this answer as this is doing what you asked for?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll accept this answer.